# IAR inline assembly using global C variable

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline, iar

I'm using IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 6.50.4 Functional Safety Version 6.50
and I can't seem to get an assembly inline instruction working.

For the background:
I'm trying to implement a context switch on an ARM7TDMI using the PIT Interrupt.
When saving the current context I have to get the address of the stack of the interrupted function, which is saved inside a global C variable, which is declared in the same c file:

```c
unsigned int* ptTask_CurrentTask;

__irq void SysIrqHandler( void )
{
// ... saving registers
__asm volatile( "LDR    R0, %0\n\t"  ::"r"(ptTask_CurrentTask)               );     
//... save the new top of stack
//select new task and restore associated registers
}
```

From what I could gather from the EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf the instruction above should be using the correct syntax.
Also I have tried different ways of formating the instruction but all I get is:

`Error[og006]: Syntax error in inline assembly: "Error[401]: Operand syntax error"`.

Now when I export the complete context saving assembly routine into a seperate .s file and call the function from c the following instruction is working just fine.
`LDR    R0, =ptTask_CurrentTask`

Since the assembly instructions on their own work, there has to be a problem with the way I'm doing the inline assembly instruction but I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried `=%0`instead of `%0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "r" constraint indicates a general-purpose register, so it ends up emitting `LDR R0, Rx` which is indeed invalid syntax. If you really want to do the actual pointer dereference in the assembly code, either embed the correct syntax directly:

```
__asm volatile( "LDR R0, [%0]\n\t" ::"r"(ptTask_CurrentTask));
```

Or, better, use the appropriate constraint to indicate that it is a memory operand (pointer) and leave the syntax to the compiler:

```
__asm volatile( "LDR R0, %0\n\t" ::"m"(ptTask_CurrentTask));
```

Or waste an extra instruction and let the compiler worry about the load:

```
__asm volatile( "MOV R0, %0\n\t" ::"r"(*ptTask_CurrentTask));
```

Whichever way, touching `r0` directly without declaring it on the clobber list is probably a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is already loading the value into a register for you due to the `r` constraint, you don't need to do the `LDR` yourself. `%0` references a register which already contains the value of `ptTask_CurrentTask`. You can check using `-S` option or disassembling that indeed the compiler does the load for you:

```
__asm volatile( ""  ::"r"(ptTask_CurrentTask));
```

Becomes:

```
    ldr     r3, .L3        # these two are generated by the compiler
    ldr     r3, [r3, #0]   # for loading the operand
    ... # here comes your asm code
.L3:
    .word   ptTask_CurrentTask
```

In this case the compiler picked `r3`. If you specifically need it in `r0`, you can use a register variable.